# RTK Query extraReducers: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'matchFulfilled')

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, redux-reducers

I am using RTK & RTK Query for state management and data fetching in my app. My store is set up via code-splitting and I get the following error related to my `extraReducer` defined in `storeNew/authSliceNew.js` at the initial loading of the app `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchFulfilled' of undefined`

What I realized so far is that if I comment out my `extraReducers` in `storeNew/authSliceNew.js`, re-load the app, and then uncomment them, they seem to be working. But if I have them uncommented right from the start, I get the error. I tried to find a solution for a couple of hours by now, but could not find anything helpful. So I would be glad if anyone could point me to the right direction.

My `storeNew/baseApi.js`

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const baseApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "api/" }),
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  tagTypes: ["User", "Budget"],
});
```

my `storeNew/authApiNew.js`

```
import { baseApi } from "./baseApi";

const authApi = baseApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    registerUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (registerCredentials) => ({
        url: "account/register",
        method: "POST",
        body: { ...registerCredentials },
      }),
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: false,
});

export const {
  useRegisterUserMutation,
} = authApi;
```

my `storeNew/authSliceNew.js`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { baseApi } from "./baseApi";

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  register_success: false,
  feedback: null,
  feedbackType: null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    resetFeedback: (state) => {
      state.feedback = null;
      state.feedbackType = null;
    },
    resetRegisterSuccess: (state) => {
      state.register_success = false;
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      baseApi.endpoints.registerUser.matchFulfilled,
      (state) => {
        state.register_success = true;
        state.feedback = null;
        state.feedbackType = null;
      }
    );
  },
});

export const authActions = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice;
```

my `storeNew/index.js`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import { baseApi } from "./baseApi";
import authSliceNew from "./authSliceNew";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [baseApi.reducerPath]: baseApi.reducer,
    authNew: authSliceNew.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(baseApi.middleware),
});

setupListeners(store.dispatch);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you access `baseApi.endpoints.registerUser.matchFulfilled` here, you have no guarantee that the `registerUser` endpoint has already been injected at that point in time (meaning: that the file injecting it has been included yet).

Export `authApi` instead, and use `authApi.endpoints.registerUser.matchFulfilled`.

`authApi` is the same object as `baseApi` (literally, a reference to the same object!), but at the time `authApi` is available to you, you have a guarantee that the `injectEndpoints` call for `registerUser` has been made.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `@rtk-query/codegen-openapi` to generate your endpoints you need some small configuration tweaks.

Add `exportName` to your config file. this will export the endpoint injected baseApi instance as the export name you provided.

`config.ts`

```
import type { ConfigFile } from "@rtk-query/codegen-openapi";

const config: ConfigFile = {
  schemaFile: "PATH_TO_SCHEMA"
  apiFile: "../utils/clients/baseApi.ts", // base API instance
  apiImport: "baseApi",
  exportName: "clientEndpoints",
  hooks: true,
  outputFiles: {
    "../services/user.ts": {
      filterEndpoints: [/user/i],
    },
    "../services/auth.ts": {
      filterEndpoints: [/auth/i],
    },
    ... //other outputFile patterns
  },
};

export default config;
```

Generated endpoint will export injectedRtkApi as clientEndpoints

`auth.generated.ts`

```
export { injectedRtkApi as clientEndpoints };
```

Use this exported clientEndpoints inside your `extraReducers`

`authSlice.ts`

```
import { clientEndpoints } from "@/services/auth";

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      clientEndpoints.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        console.log("fulfilled", action);
        const stateCopy = state;
        stateCopy.userId = action?.payload?.user?.id;
        stateCopy.accessToken = action?.payload?.token;
      }
    );
  },
});
```

ref: [rtk-query/usage/code-generation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/code-generation#:%7E:text=petApi.ts%27%2C-,exportName,-%3A%20%27petApi%27)